# Defining axis values r

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I would simply like to have an x-axis from 0 to 6 like "0 1 2 3 4 5 6". But the default solution by R is like in the picture

[image]

I tried to modify the x-axis with the following code, among others, but can't get this done

```
ggplot(subset(data, question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")), aes(x=question, y=mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", width = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd, ymax = mean+sd, width = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Here's the data

```
structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), n = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), mean = c(5.14285714285714, 5, 5.57142857142857, 
5.28571428571429), sd = c(0.899735410842437, 1.29099444873581, 
1.13389341902768, 0.951189731211342)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

SOS

Comment: You need `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: Maybe since You used `coord_flip()` it's about y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `scale_y_continuous` since you used `coord_flip()`:

```
ggplot(subset(data, question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")), aes(x=question, y=mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", width = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd, ymax = mean+sd, width = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

[image]